# Is there API for files comparison in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, file-comparison

Since file comparison can be executed from vscode using at least a couple of ways that I am aware of:

1. code --diff file1 file2
2. command palette: "File: Compare Active File With..."

I was wondering if there could be an api for comparing two files that I could use in an extension?
I couldn't find it in the official page though. Maybe it's in the works/plans already?

Answer (score 6):

You can open a diff view programmatically by invoking the `"vscode.diff"` command with two `vscode.Uri` instances:

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.diff", uri1, uri2)
```

There's also optional `title` and `options` arguments, see the [docs on built-in commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands) for more info.

Comment: I'd also like to add that the uri1, and uri2 are of type vscode.Uri. 
like: let url1 = vscode.Uri.file("path-to-your-file");

Comment: true! I'd just give a quick example how to create a uri from path. To me that wasn't immediately obvious, I am a noob! :)

Comment: You are an angel! Thank you so much!